# MATLAB: Unit test: make sure to test every line

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am using unit tests in MATLAB. How can I verify that my test actually executes every single line of the underlying function/class at least once? Is it possible to use the timeit function? What's best practice?

Comment: MATLAB's unit test framework provides [code coverage functionality](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverageplugin-class.html)

Comment: Code coverage is the key word I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATE***

[More functionality](https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2017/10/16/cobertura-code-coverage/) with R2017b.

***/UPDATE***

@excaza's comment is spot on, you can leverage the [CodeCoveragePlugin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverageplugin-class.html) to generate a code coverage report for the source code of interest.

However, I should warn that using code coverage to determine that your test suite adequately tests every line of code is probably the wrong way to think about code coverage. What code coverage is good for is telling you what you know is not covered. So if you see an uncovered line in the source code you know you should add at least one test for that line. However, it is important to note that if you see a covered line that does not mean that the line is doing the right thing, or that it even has a test thats specifically tests that line. It may be that the line is being covered implicitly from another test, and it may not be producing the right result. Determining that the covered code is actually tested explicitly is a much better goal, but is also more complicated.

Good luck!

Comment: You're absolute right. However, my first goal is to look for code lines that haven't been covered at all.